# Error query Sql Server insert, not correct value format C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have a problem with inserting data into a `sql server 2012`.
My problem is that when I save `Quantita`and `Prezzo`the values are changed! what can it be?. `Quantita` and `Prezzo` as `Money` values are taken from a datagridview I leave you under an example with the image of the `datagridview` used for insertion and the result of insertion into the database.

**VALUE WITHIN DATAGRIDVIEW:**

[image]

**AFTER INSERT INTO SQL-SERVER:**

[image]

```
 SqlConnection conn = db.apriconnessione();
            SqlTransaction sqlTran = conn.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {
                //avvio la transazione

                SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
                command.Transaction = sqlTran;

                //InserimentoBolla
                DateTime dataconvertita = Convert.ToDateTime(labelDATADDTMOD.Text);
                command.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Bolla ON";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Bolla(NumeroDDT,IdCantiere,DataDDT,Agente,RagioneSociale,CodiceCliente,RiferimentiInterni,Importo,Destinazione,Filiale,Magazzino,Preparato,Vettore,TipoTrasporto) VALUES('" + labelNUMDDTMOD.Text+"','"+IdCantiere+"',convert(datetime,'"+dataconvertita+"', 103),'" + labelAgenteMOD.Text+"','"+labelRagioneSocialeMOD.Text+"','"+int.Parse(labelCodiceClienteMOD.Text)+"','"+labelRIFInternoMOD.Text+"','"+float.Parse(labelImportoMOD.Text)+"','"+labelDestMOd.Text+"','"+labelFilialeMOD.Text+"','"+labelMagazzinoMOD.Text+"','"+labelPreparatodaMOD.Text+"','"+labelvettoreMOD.Text+"','"+labelTipoTrasportoMOD.Text+"')";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Bolla OFF";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //fine bolla

                //inserimento articolo

                for (int rows = 0; rows < dataGridViewArticoli.Rows.Count; rows++)
                {

                        string Fornitore = dataGridViewArticoli.Rows[rows].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                        string ModelloFornitore = dataGridViewArticoli.Rows[rows].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                        string SiglaMetel = dataGridViewArticoli.Rows[rows].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

                        string CodiceMetel = dataGridViewArticoli.Rows[rows].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

                        string CodiceInterno = dataGridViewArticoli.Rows[rows].Cells[4].Value.ToString();

                        string Descrizione = dataGridViewArticoli.Rows[rows].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

                        float prezzo = float.Parse(dataGridViewArticoli.Rows[rows].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
                       // MessageBox.Show(" "+prezzo);
                        float quantita = float.Parse(dataGridViewArticoli.Rows[rows].Cells[8].Value.ToString());

                   // MessageBox.Show("Quantita: "+quantita);
                        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ArticoloCantiere(IdCantiere,IdUtente,CodArt,CodMarca,CodiceInterno,ModelloFornitore,Prezzo,Quantita,Fornitore,Importato) VALUES('" + IdCantiere + "','"+u.IdUtente+"','" + CodiceMetel + "','" + SiglaMetel + "','" + CodiceInterno + "','" + ModelloFornitore + "','" + prezzo + "','" + quantita + "','COMET','BOLLA')";
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                //fine inserimento articolo

                //conferma delle transazioni con la commit
                sqlTran.Commit();


            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                sqlTran.Rollback();
                MessageBox.Show("Errore nell'inserimento "+ex);
            }

            conn.Close();

            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
```

Comment: Please i have trouble to understand what are you saying can you please correct a little your grammar ?

Comment: Ok one moment....

Comment: Try : float prezzo = dataGridViewArticoli.Rows[rows].Cells[6].Value;

Comment: *Please* read about and start using [Prepared Statements](http://bobby-tables.com/).  Your code is highly susceptible to SQL Injection and very prone to experience odd quirks and problems (and very likely to be why you opened this question to begin with) because of the string concatenation used to build the query.

Comment: What are the data types in the data base? Are they decimal?

Comment: @Scath The types are money in the database by float software

Comment: @Esperadoce done

Comment: **NEVER** store data as `money`. It's a _retreival type_ used for select queries at display time to convert raw values to get currency formats right, but it lacks the precision to do accurate calculations with money.

Comment: @ Joel Coehoorn >>>but it lacks the precision to do accurate calculations with money<<< Can you provide us with the example of such "not accuracy"? It's not true at all

Comment: @jdweng If I do as you tell me you made me a mistake

Comment: To have accurate calculations, NEVER use float or real. But money is a precise data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You insert string values with ',' separator into `money` data type, and this is a problem.

First of all, in SQL Server the decimal separator is ALWAYS '.', not the ','.

Second, you should not pass `numbers` as `strings`

Here is the code to reproduce your problem:

```
declare @t table(col money)
insert into @t values
('1,44');

select *
from @t;
----------

 -- 144,00
```

Money data type accepts input with **`','`** separator, but it treats it **not as decimal separator but thousand separator.**

So to resolve it, the best way is pass in numbers as numbers, the worst thing you can do is just replace ',' with '.' before insert:

```
declare @t table(col money)
insert into @t values
(replace ('1,44', ',', '.'));

select *
from @t;
-----
---1,44
```

Comment: I did not know this, however the values of the datagridview I have to include are loaded by a file containing the articles, if I try to replace all the strings with quantita and prezzo instead of, I put the. , It should work?

Comment: Yes, exactly so, you should pass in values with a point(.) as decimal separator, not with comma (,)

Comment: It works perfectly, if I find you in the street I offer you a coffee

Comment: Tanti saluti da Roma :)

Comment: Saluti da Bologna

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a breakpoint at:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and double check that both values are correct for:

```
prezzo and quantita
```

edit: if the values are as expected, please check sql data types.

I would also suggest adding sql parameters, otherwise your code is vulnerable to sql injections:

```
INSERT  INTO 
        ArticoloCantiere
        (field1, field2...) 
        VALUES  
        (@value1, @value2...)
```

then:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value1", <somevalue>));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value1", <somevalue>));
...
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parameterized queries. This is a **BIG DEAL** in terms of security, to the point where if you're not doing this you're practically *begging* to get hacked.

But this isn't just about security. Parameterized queries *will also likely fix your formatting issue*, because they can also automatically account for things like date formats and text values with single quotes in the data. As a bonus, you'll also typically get a (very small, but measurable) performance boost.

Here's how it will look:

```
//putting this all in one sql string to execute in one DB call eliminates the need for C# to manage transactions.
// If you're nervous about it, you can add "BEGIN TRANSACTION" and "COMMIT" statements to the SQL.
string sql = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Bolla ON;\n"
    + "INSERT INTO Bolla (NumeroDDT,IdCantiere,DataDDT,Agente,RagioneSociale,CodiceCliente,RiferimentiInterni,Importo,Destinazione,Filiale,Magazzino,Preparato,Vettore,TipoTrasporto)\n"
    + " VALUES(\n" 
    + "@NumeroDDT, @IdCantiere, @DataDDT, @Agente, @RagioneSociale, @CodiceCliente, @RiferimentiInterni, @Importo, @Destinazione, @Filiale, @Magazzino, @Preparato, @Vettore, @TipoTrasporto);\n"
    + "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Bolla OFF;";


using (var conn = db.apriconnessione())
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    //I have to guess at column types and lengths. Update these parameters to match your DB columns
    cmd.Paramerers.Add("@NumeroDDT", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = labelNUMDDTMOD.Text;
    cmd.Paramerers.Add("@IdCantiere", SqlDbType.Int).Value = IdCantiere;
    cmd.Paramerers.Add("@DataDDT", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(labelDATADDTMOD.Text);
    cmd.Paramerers.Add("@Agente", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = labelAgenteMOD.Text;
    cmd.Paramerers.Add("@RagioneSociale", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = labelRagioneSocialeMOD.Text;
    cmd.Paramerers.Add("@CodiceCliente", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(labelCodiceClienteMOD.Text);
    cmd.Paramerers.Add("@RiferimentiInterni", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = labelRIFInternoMOD.Text;
    cmd.Paramerers.Add("@Importo", SqlDbType.Float).Value = float.Parse(labelImportoMOD.Text); //probably should be double or decimal
    cmd.Paramerers.Add("@Destinazione", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = labelDestMOd.Text;
    cmd.Paramerers.Add("@Filiale", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = labelFilialeMOD.Text;
    cmd.Paramerers.Add("@Magazzino", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = labelMagazzinoMOD.Text;
    cmd.Paramerers.Add("@Preparato", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = labelPreparatodaMOD.Text;
    cmd.Paramerers.Add("@Vettore", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = labelvettoreMOD.Text;
    cmd.Paramerers.Add("@TipoTrasporto", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = labelTipoTrasportoMOD.Text;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Note there are some other improvements in here, too. I didn't re-write the other parts of your code just for the fun of it. But this query parameters are the important part.